# Search Feature in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Good day

i am developing an application that has several pages in it,
instead of the user having to go through the stress of navigating to the required page
i will like to add a search feature in which when the user type in the required page keyword
it will take the user to the page without stress

I mean the user will type in the keyword for that particular page to bring out the theme or title of the page when the user clicks the title or theme of the page it will now take the user to the whole page for example page one title is "victory in christ" when the user types this keyword/title/theme and click on search it will bring out the particular page of that title

How can i implement this in windows phone 8 app

Reply soon thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

you could maintain all the titles of your pages in a collection. As the user tries to search, u  check if the searched term is available in the collection. If it is, you simply navigate to the appropriate page.